# How to filter with comparison operator in rethinkdb

Tags: php, rethinkdb

```
 $students = r\table("students")->map(function($x) {
            return $x;
            })->filter(array(
                'department_id'=>994,
                'age'=> 12
                ))->run($conn);
```

The above code, just outputs students who are 12 years old. How do I change that so that it will output those students who are 12 and lesser?

I tried:

```
->filter(array(
    'department_id'=>994,
    'age'=> r\row("age")->lt(12)
```

But that doesn't work. I found lots of online resources for javascript samples. I need it in php. How can I do that?

Comment: why you use id here? I think it's not working. because if it works then the only single student will return based on id (as id be unique per student).BTW you need to use:- `$students = r.table("users").filter(
    r.row("age").lt(12);
).run(conn, callback);`  .Reference Link:-https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/filter/

Comment: @AlivetoDie, ops that suppose to be department id

Comment: @AlivetoDie i need it in php

Comment: what i saw it's only available in:- JavaScript | Python | Ruby | Java